# Use observer pattern ot throw exceptions in model

Tags: java, exception, observer-pattern

Is it more likely to use the observer pattern in Java to handel for example game rules like in some simple games or just throw exceptions to handel these in the UserInterface classes?

Each time an user clicks onto a button on the UserInterface, this controller just delegates this action to the model with the data in it. The model decides whether the data is correct compared to some game rules or just throw exceptions to handle this in the controller and react on each custom exception. E.g. (in model class; don't need to show you the corresponding controller class):

Observer Pattern with PropertyChangeListener and PropertyChangeSupport:

```
public void setPlayerNames(ArrayList<String> playerNames) 
{
    if(playerNames.size() == 0)
       propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("pleaseEnterAtLeastOnePlayerName);
    else
       startGame();
}
```

And with some custom exceptions in the model:

```
public void setPlayerNames(ArrayList<String> playerNames) throws NoPlayerException
{
    if(playerNames.size() == 0)
       throw new NoPlayerException();
    else
       startGame();
}
```

Which of these methods complies more to the MVC paradigma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one uses a PropertyChangeListener to fire events that have nothing to do with property changes. Using an event-based model to implement validation doesn't look very intuitive or easy to use.

The second one throws an exception to signal an illegal argument. Using IllegalArgumentException is the best way to signal such a problem. But it should be done only to protect the model from entering into an invalid state, not to implement validation. The controller should check the validity of the list *before* passing it to the model.

Comment: Yes this is right, but if you write a simple API to loosely couple the game logic from the user interface how do you do that. The problem is: If someone implements a different GUI and wants to enter data which is not sufficient, the model (logic) has to tell the GUI what to do. The controller ist on the UI level and has NOTHING to do with the logic, so checking if data is correct can not be checked in the controller. I learned to use Observer pattern, but is it right to use exception handling? UI calls model calls Data level (GUI --> model --> Data). NEVER the other way round.

Comment: Protecting the model state against an incorrect GUI, and throwing meaningful exceptions is not a problem. But that should help the GUI developer to implement correct validation. It shouldn't be the validation itself. For example, a GUI could be internationalized. The model shouldn't care about it. It's the job of the controller to deal with i18n. Other example: some GUI could need HTML-formatted error messages, whereas another could want purely textual ones, and another will disable the button until the data is valid. The model shouldn't deal with these differences.

Comment: Yes but which is better: Observer pattern or exception handling in UserInterface in your case, if there is some illegal case?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from providing methods in the model to check that the data are valid or not. The controller should simply call these methods. No need for events or exceptions. And the controller **will** have to know the logic of the game. You can't implement a GUI for a poker game without knowing anything about poker.

Comment: Yes I know, but you can implement a GUI for a poker game and crash the logic itself, by simply entering wrong or tricky data. If the model doesn't check it, it will be okay for it. No handling of propertyChanges or exceptions on the GUI will not prevent crashing the game through the model?!

Comment: As I said: the model should maintain its invariants by throwing exceptions in case of invalid arguments. You should simply not base the validation in the GUI on these exceptions. The validation logic is like the brakes in your car. You use the brakes all the time to avoid accidents. The exceptions thrown by the model are like the airbag. It should never be used, except to prevent really serious issues in case the driver forgot to use the brakes.